# Get sigaction structure

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, sigaction

Trying to build paho_c_pub.c with help of Visual Studio 2019 on my Raspberry Pi machine connected via ssh. Code uses `structure sigaction` from <signal.h> that is not visible by compiler:

```
Error       invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct sigaction’
Error       storage size of ‘sa’ isn’t known
```

I have no such errors when I build code in console:

```
cc paho_c_sub.c pubsub_opts.c -o paho_c_sub -l paho-mqtt3as
```

What is wrong with Visual Studio C project configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to have

```c
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
```

before the

```c
#include <signal.h>
```

as described in [man 3 sigaction](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), in the *Feature Test Macro requirements for glibc* part of the Synopsis.

Whenever you compile code, you should enable warnings (`-Wall`).

Without the above definition, the `sigaction()` function is not exposed, and your compiler uses the standard C rules on determining exactly what to pass to it.  It happens to work, because it takes an int and two pointers as parameters; but when warnings are enabled (and especially when warnings are treated as errors, as in your Visual Studio 2019 environment), the compiler points out this issue.
Adding the `#define` should make both work correctly, without relying on happenstance.